# Explanation needed with Django and AMP logic using 1 url

Tags: javascript, amp, python, django

I'm using AMP at one of my parts of the website with Django template and python, my question is what will happen to a page (*SEO wise) if I take and break an AMPed page (only on desktop) and leave the page AMPed on mobile?!

To be more specific, I have made a full AMP page for both mobile and desktop which use the url (/example-amp-url) and now I need to add a widget to the page which is rendered with js and not AMPed at all but render it only on desktop.

Any one knows how it would impact on my SEO? Because for now in my site-map this page is AMPed both on mobile search and on desktop page (if Im losing the AMP on desktop it is fine but if I lose both its a huge problem thats why Im afraid to test it)

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters!

Comment: Cheers, thanks! :)